# The difference between "as is" and "to be" in Magic Draw?

Tags: model, magic-draw

I have an assignment to create a model in Magic Draw. I need to make the assignment in two ways in "as is" model and "to be", but as I looked around the internet I could not have what I need.

***Has anyone got any idea what I'm talking about?***

Comment: https://www.nomagic.com/attachments/article/412/uml-intensive_framework_for_modeling_software_requirements.pdf (from the MagicDraw site)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your assignment is to document the current state of a system, and then design new features.  Probably two different diagrams.  I would start w/current state, and then modify it w/the new features.  Good luck.